# Directly add Clip icon to Home Screen of an iphone when webapp is first accessed

Tags: iphone

I want to know that is there any way that I can add my webapp's clip icon to the Homescreen of an iPhone directly when user first acessess my webpage through the Safari ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the only way your webapp can be added to the user's home screen is if he/she manually does it.